# How Do I Detect Outliers From Clustered Data Points?

Tags: clustering, outliers

I have a data set on a single variable (say, x). Below is the point plot of the data. From the plot it is seen that data points form few clusters around values, say 4, [1.5,2] and 0. Can we say that if a point lies outside this interval, it is an outlier? Also, can anyone suggest by looking at the plot how I can detect outliers from this data set?[image]

Answer (score 2):

An outlier is a surprising point. Do any of these points surprise you?  This is a matter for a substantive expert, and you have not even told us what the variable is.

Sometimes a graph of the data (or a numerical summary) shows some points that seem surprising, even to a naive observer. From my view, there are no such points here. But maybe there are.